# Authenticate against client Active Directories in a Web Single Sign On

Tags: authentication, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, wif

I've been scratching my head over this issue for over a week. We have a web app that we would like to implement SSO for. SSO with windows active directories of our clients (i.e. we essentially need to authenticate against our clients' active directories without much trouble)

The only thing I am 100% sure about is that I will needed a security token service that will have to communicate with an Identity Provider. My question:

- Which service is most suitable for the above scenario (AD FS? OpenID  & OAuth 2.0? SAML 2.0 and shibboleth?)
- How will I connect to the active directories of the clients? Maybe I'm not understanding how the STS is to be used, could anyone clarify? I'm working with an Azure Web App
- Will there have to be a different IdP for each client? Will the client have to do more than just give us standard information? What would this info be?

...should I be using Windows Identity Foundation?

HELP :( ... this is an SOS

If anyone could clarify at all,  I will forever be grateful. I normally upvote anything I find helpful and accept whichever answer is the best so feel free to answer with what you think might be useful in helping me understand how I can achieve what I am after.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx and http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-on/

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Identity and Access option for visual studio 2013 is non existent

Comment: you're right. It's not available yet to VS 2013 http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/visual-studio-2013-where-is-identity.html

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio do you by any chance know how to connect the tenants to their active directories? If I create a separate tenant for each client, how would I authenticate against their on-prem windows AD? Would I do it by configuring the client's tenant with their domain? How does this work?

Comment: unfortunately no. Do you have a pluralsight signature? http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/wif-patterns-premise-cloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the three options I know:

As you mention one option is **ADFS** this solution means that your customers should install and expose Adfs. ADFS means Active directory-Federation Services, so in this case your application needs to speak WS-Fed (not oauth). Typically if the user is inside the LAN adfs uses integrated auth, if not it will prompt credentials.

**WAAD** is a new service from Azure, it allows companies to expose their directories to use in cloud applications. With this approach your customers need an account in Azure, create a directory and use the dir sync agent. Your application will talk SAMLP with WAAD.

**Auth0** is an authentication broker that allows developers to use social but also enterprise identity providers like AD but also google apps, waad, adfs, salesforce, etc. if your customer only has AD you will provide him an msi for a windows service, that will bridge the company AD with your auth0 account, you can have as many AD as you want. Your application speak oauth with Auth0. This agent supports kerberos authentication as well. The following graph explains this solution:

[image]

Disclaimer: I work for Auth0.

Comment: ooo interesting, this is the first time I'm hearing about Auth0. Do you  have a recommended reading on it that I can have a skim through?

Comment: Yes, if you are ASP.Net check our [setup tutorial](https://docs.auth0.com/aspnet-tutorial). Here is a list of [supported providers](https://docs.auth0.com/identityproviders).

Answer (score 1):

WIF doesn't support SAML or OAuth.

Your application is in Azure.

Suggest add WIF to the application and then "bind" to Azure Active Directory. In VS 2013, use the "Change Authentication" feature for this.

Make the application multi-tenanted.

Each customer has their own tenant. User DirSync to sync. each customer AD with their AAD tenant. (That gives same sign-on). Adding ADFS to each customer gives single sign-on.

However, the customers will probably push back on this because of perceptions around security.

Comment: EXACTLY! How can I avoid same sign-on and do a Web SSO instead? Without the directory synchronization? Is it not possible at all?

Comment: Can I do it outside of the MS realm?

Comment: You can federate without DirSync as per http://cloudidentityblog.com/2013/07/19/waad-as-idp/. Otherwise, just use AAD credentials but that's not SSO. Not aware of anything outside of Microsoft realm.